# How to return a value from a row based on another column in power BI?

Tags: powerbi

In BI, is there a way to write a function that looks at Name 2 and pulls the score from the second column for that individual? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

| Name | Score | Name 2 | Score 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 100 | Sue |  |
| Sue | 80 | Nick |  |
| Nick | 50 | Bob |  |

Answer (score 3):

If you want to implement it as a calculated column in your data model:

```
Score 2 =
VAR Current_Name = Table[Name 2]
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table[Score] ), ALL ( Table ), Table[Name] = Current_Name )
```

If you want to implement it as a measure:

```
Score 2 =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table[Score] ),
    ALL ( Table )
    Table[Name] IN VALUES ( Table[Name 2] )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You sure can with the following measure

```
_score2 =
SUMX (
    'fact',
    VAR _0 = 'fact'[Name 2]
    VAR _1 =
        CALCULATE (
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'fact'[Score] ), 'fact'[Name] = _0 ),
            ALL ( 'fact' )
        )
    RETURN
        _1
)
```

[image: Solution]